# In Django, should a function to reshuffle objects for a specifc view go into the model or the view?

Tags: django, view, model, code-organization

I'm asking for general guidance on what functionality should go into the view code versus the model code.

Specifically, I have a function that takes a list of objects and shuffles them into a list of lists based on whether or not a field has changed. For example:

```
[{a:1,...},{a:1,...},{a:2,...},{a:1,...},{a:1,...}]
```

will be transformed into

```
[[{a:1,...},{a:1,...}],[{a:2,...}],[{a:1,...},{a:1,...}]]
```

The purpose of this transformation is to prep the data for rendering in a template as nested loops.

Should I create a model function like `group_objects(queryset)` or should I put this logic into the view? More importantly, what's the thinking behind your recommendation?

Comment: Is this transformation presentation-specific (i.e. it's only for a specific template)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this function is for template rendering it should be a custom template tag (or filter).

And look at [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) filter, may be it can be used for your task.

Comment: +1 I never even noticed that regroup filter. Guess you learn every day :D

Answer (score 0):

The Django docs specifically state that table level functionality should preferably be implemented in a model manager ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods)). So I guess that if you want to follow the Django standards you'd implement it in the model manager.

Comment: The Django docs also provide means for doing this sort of thing [in the template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) in case it's presentation specific.

Comment: I wouldn't call this "table-level functionality" if the purpose is organizing data for display.